# Is the digital series H+ based on any popular fiction work?

Tags: nanotechnology, h+

I have been following [digital series H+](http://www.youtube.com/HplusDigitalSeries?feature=etp-gs-hpl) on YouTube. Was wondering if it is loosely based on (or inspired by) any existing Sci-fi work. Any pointers towards similar sci-fi will be appreciated.

[IMDB description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1730523/):

> A future-set story in which a virus has wiped out most of the human race, and those still alive have their minds linked to the Internet 24 hours a day. Here, a viral incident leads to a new world order.

Comment: Can you give us the premise for the series? Even if we have not seen it, we may be able to recognize related works.

Comment: I've added the description from IMDB. If it is not accurate or is for the wrong show then please roll back the edit.

Comment: A story set in the future where humanity is engaged in a transhuman experiment called H+ which connects everyone to a world-wide network. A terrorist-created computer virus kills everyone connected to the network and leads to a New World Order.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Xantec. As the description says its a scifi based on transhumanism (nanotechnology). Its a youtube only (digital) series by Bryan singer.

Comment: @Raghu - did the answer suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, its producers have made no comments regarding their inspiration for the series. The transhumanism (also known as H+) portion of the show may have been inspired by any number of [science-fiction portrayals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumanism_in_fiction) of H+, such as Deus Ex or Blade Runner.

The computer virus that wipes out those with the implants could be based on media that portrays the loss of electronics, similar to the upcoming TV show Revolution or the video game Black Ops 2 (both created after H+, but likely drawing their inspirations from some of the same sources).

Comment: It seems like wiping out technology was one of the possible endings for Deus Ex and Deus Ex:Invisible War. The themes of a New World Order and a secret war are staples of the series. The [H+]^3 symbol is used to denote humans with cybernetics in the prequel Deus Ex:Human Revolution, the third game in the series.